# Setting Element To Position:Fixed Results In Ugly Page Jump

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

On this website: EDIT

I want `$("#menu")` to be affixed to the top of the page once you scroll past it, kind of like the header here: http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront

The problem is when I do this, the page jumps up. I thought I could solve this with `$("#placeHolder")` but that doesn't work either.

How can I do this like on the Battlefront website?

My jquery (complete with debounce function) is below

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() > $("#menu").height())
{
$("#menu").addClass("fixed");
}
else 
{
$("#menu").removeClass("fixed");
}   
}, 250);
myEfficientFn();
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: When I see your website, it seems the menu should simply always be set in `position: fixed`

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that adding a class with `position: fixed;` property will not overwrite the `position: relative;` of your id `#menu`, because browsers have preference for IDs properties.
You could instead declare `position: relative` in jQuery.

Then:

You first have to catch the initial (before you start scrolling) `$("#menu").offset().top` and not `$("#menu").height()` and store it in a variable.

and then the condition should be:

```
$("#menu").css("position","relative");

menuOffset = $("#menu").offset().top

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(document).scrollTop() > menuOffset ) {
        $("#menu").css("position","fixed");
    }
    else {
        $("#menu").css("position","relative");
    }
});
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9jc2by8w/

—

although when I see your website, I definitely think you don't really need jQuery here, simply style your #menu this way:

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top:10px;
    left:50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qznstyfc/

*Prolétaires de tous les pays, unissez-vous !*

Comment: I don't think this works... the class change doesn't apply even when I scroll past the element.

Comment: Well, the issue must then be in your CSS with your class `.fixed`. It worked in my fiddle, but I applied `$("#menu").css("position","fixed")` instead of `$("#menu").addClass("fixed")`

Comment: I see the issue: adding a class `.fixed` does not overwrite the CSS `position: relative;` of your ID `#menu`, because the browser always has preference for the IDs styles. I update my answer.

Comment: If you check the site now, I made the changes but I still get the ugly jump up.

Comment: There are several things that do not work: when your `#menu` is styled with 'position: fixed;' it is not centered anymore, and you have the 250 delay in the end of your debounce function which is hard to control. Sure you need jQuery for that? See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make `#menu`'s width 100%.

Also, store `#menu`'s original offset (at page load) in a variable and test if the window has scrolled past that when applying the `fixed` class:

```
var fromTop = document.getElementById('menu').getBoundingClientRect().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > fromTop)
        $("#menu").addClass("fixed");
    else 
        $("#menu").removeClass("fixed");       
})
```

Add debounce as needed.

I was just using this from someone's CSS-related question, and added your code to it for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fzhg4cof/2/